# Split long string into an javascript array using regex

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I wish to split a long string into a smaller userID only javascript array, but I can't figure out how to do it.

The string looks like this:

```
22;#Jimmy,, Love,#i:0#.w|towncountry.com\\LoveJimmy,#JLove@towncountry.com,#,#Jimmy,, Love,#,#,#;#334;#Jane Austin,#i:0#.w|towncountry.com\\JAustin,#JAustin@towncountry.com,#,#Jane Austin,#,#,#;#433;#Charlie Clearfolk,#i:0#.w|towncountry.com\\CClearfolk,#CClearfolk@towncountry.com,#,#Charlie Clearfolk,#,#,#
```

I wish to create an array that contain the userIDs, which are:

```
JLove, JAustin, CClearfolk
```

Comment: Your string looks completely random

Comment: `string.match(/regexp/g)` will return an array of all the matches for the regular expression. So just write a regexp that matches the username parts of the string.

Comment: If you describe the string format, we can offer some advice. (For example, what's the type of data and their order in the string?)

Comment: hi guys, the data is a multi user value column lookup using Spservices in a sharepoint 2013 environment. the string returned seems to start with and ID number  and end with 3 # hash tags. I'm super bad with regex, but I did find this shows me the email address..`([\\w-+]+(?:\\.[\\w-+]+)*@(?:[\\w-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,7})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get every word which is between `#` and `@`. Something like this:

```
/(\w+)(?=@)/g
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oC1yF5/3)

---

**Full Code:**

```js
var str = "22;#Jimmy,, Love,#i:0#.w|towncountry.com\\LoveJimmy,#JLove@towncountry.com,#,#Jimmy,, Love,#,#,#;#334;#Jane Austin,#i:0#.w|towncountry.com\\JAustin,#JAustin@towncountry.com,#,#Jane Austin,#,#,#;#433;#Charlie Clearfolk,#i:0#.w|towncountry.com\\CClearfolk,#CClearfolk@towncountry.com,#,#Charlie Clearfolk,#,#,#   ";
var result =  str.match(/(\w+)(?=@)/g);
document.write(result);
```

Comment: you don't need the negative lookahead there: /(\w+)(?=@)/g

Comment: Wow, thanks shafizadeh! This works perfectly - appreciate the help!!

Comment: @user1667178 You are welcome ..

Comment: @sweaver2112 You're right ... I will improve it ...!